# C++ Patching Calls In Exe

Tags: c++, windows, api, hook

Problem:

I am injecting into a program and patching calls but I was wondering if there is any way to walk through the application line by line and find specific calls.  _IE: Lets say the program 'Foo.exe' has a call to **MessageBox** at some location in memory.

If I did the following code: ( just a rough idea )

```
a = GetModuleHandle ( "<dll>" ); 
b = GetProcAddress ( a , "<name>" );
swap ( b , (DWORD)*fake_function );
```

-- Everything works out fine, until you start calling the actual function - which creates a huge loop that goes on forever (ouch).

Now I am not sure about this and I may be wrong but ... does the above code replace the 'Foo.exe' calls in memory, or does it replace the dll's function with 'fake_function'?

I am interested in a few things ...

*A )* How can I find all the memory locations in 'Foo,exe' that call **MessageBox** and replace the memory locations with a call to 'fake_function'?

*B )* How does detours solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to locate all the instances where MessageBox gets called, instead you can hook the function. It seems like you have the general idea down, but what you want to do is walk the PE import table for the module in question. When you're walking it, you look for the function you want to hook and then you do the swap. From then on whenever the module calls the MessageBox function it will look for a reference to the function in the import table and find the address to your function where it previously would have found the address to Microsoft's implementation of MessageBox. In your function you can do whatever you want and you can even call the original address of the MessageBox function that you would have had to save upon swap.

Comment: So, in the above code, I can save the address 'a' (memory address of: MessageBox_function).  And then I can use assembly to call it? ( rough idea w/o other variables )  __asm { call a }  Wouldnt this go into a infinite loop and call my 'fake_function' instead?

Comment: I think your rough idea code might be off. It looks like you are getting the exported address of the MessageBox function from whatever DLL it resides in. Swapping a pointer to the MessageBox function with a pointer to your function will not actually "hook" the MessageBox call. It will only replace memory for the variable containing the pointer to MessageBox (b) with your a pointer to your MessageBox replacement function. You could simplify your rough idea code by doing b = fake_function, so it doesn't seem to be what you want.

Comment: Your module imports the address to MessageBox. You want to change the import such that it points to your MessageBox function instead of Microsoft's. The code you have only retrieves the address to function from a module.

Comment: Sorry my last comment was suppose to be 'b' not 'a'.  I guess I dont want to really hook anything.  What I want to do is just replace all calls to MessageBox in 'Foo.exe' to instead call my fake_function.  But I also want to be able to call MessageBox in fake_function without causing a big loop.

Comment: So if you are using LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress only to get the address of MessageBox so you can do a search and replace in the entire executable, make sure you aren't replacing the value found in the import table. If you do, that could cause the loop you are seeing.

Comment: This may be of particular use: see "Importing Functions" in  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx